# Having BSOD problems, Win 7 Memory Disgnostic hangs at 21% every time

Tags: windows-7, memory, bsod

I have been having blue screen problems ever since I built my (first) diy PC this past Christmas.  Various people on various sites have suggested it's a RAM problem so I tried running the built in Win 7 Memory Diagnostic.

The extended test hangs at 21% of the first pass every time. This seems to be a problem other people have come across over time, but there isn't a satisfactory answer on the whole internet that I can find.

Does anyone have any clue here? And also, my blue screens seem to revolve around fltmgr.sys, ntfs.sys, if that matters to anyone. (Plus I've had a page fault blue screen in the past).

Comment: Run multiple full runs of MemTestx86 and report the results by editing your question.

Comment: Ok I have Memtest bootable running 7 passes. So far in pass 2/7 it's encountered 7 errors. This will take hours but later after this test I will run it again with each stick individually.

Comment: Your results so far indicate bad memory.  Do our suggestion run Memtestx86 on one stick

Answer (score 1):

> The extended test hangs at 21% of the first pass every time. This seems to be a problem other people have come across over time, but there isn't a satisfactory answer on the whole internet that I can find.

I think the standard answer is replace the RAM in Slot 1 or Bank 1 (using 1-based math, and assuming 21% puts it in the first slot or pair of banks).

If you swap the memory among slots or banks and the problem moves around, then its almost certainly bad RAM. If you have 4 sticks, you can also remove pairs at a time to try and isolate the bad stick (or sticks).

It *could* be the memory manager on the motherboard (the MMU), but its usually a bad stick (or sticks) of RAM.

I doubt its the CPU because the first thing it does is test its registers (which memory gets read into (with some hand waiving)). If registers were bad, then you would not get past POST.

Otherwise, what do you consider acceptable? And what was unacceptable about the other answers you uncovered?

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense. The memory test is supposed to tell you if you have a bad stick. If it hangs at a certain percent until you remove the bad stick then what is the purpose of the test? When will it ever finish and actually tell you something?

Comment: @WakeDemons3 - what doesn't make sense? It sounds like you have a bad stick of RAM, and your tests are telling you such. Programs execute from memory, and not storage. If the memory read corrupts your program while its in memory, then such is life. There's nothing you can do about it except replace the RAM. What doesn't make sense to me is you are refusing to accept the results :)

Comment: That's not the purpose of a diagnostic test: to freeze until you figure the problem out yourself with trial and error. It's supposed to finish and TELL YOU a problem. But whatever. I'll just toss out my brand new 81 day old RAM sticks and buy new ones.

Comment: @WakeDemons3 - I can tell your from experience in doing the same: memory is a constant problem. I've had shops from California ship me 4 bad sticks of RAM. Its like they keep reselling the bad RAM until they find someone who does not RMA it. Buy your RAM from a reputable dealer. Be weary of the least expensive stuff you find on the open markets.

Comment: *"That's not the purpose of a diagnostic test: to freeze until you figure the problem out yourself with trial and error...."* - you should file a bug report with the program vendor. Otherwise, if you just used Super User as a forum to complain (and not really looking for an answer to a questions), then you should take it elsewhere because its a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Switched the RAM sticks around and it still hangs on 21%. That would be a mighty coincidence if the second RAM stick (now in slot 1 instead of 3) was the exact same amount of broken. I conclude Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool is a POS. Still going to just buy new RAM. Btw I use Newegg and only buy G.Skill Ripjaws X, or Sniper Series.

Comment: @WakeDemons3 - Use MemTestx86 and update your question.  In the mean time you need to lose your attitude.  You are asking for people for help and provide their knowledge on a particular subject.  This answer is correct, it is sometimes required to test each memory module by itself to determine which one is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

I see that it has been more than a year since the original question was asked, but please let me clear some of the confusion up:  This is **normal behavior** for this particular tool.

Even if your RAM is good, the "Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool" **will very often, if not always, hang on 21%** when running the Extended tests!!!  But it is not permanently hung...  whatever test is running at that time just takes a long time to finish.

To be clear:  if a pass using Microsoft's Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool seems to hang on 21% when running the Extended tests, it does NOT mean that your ram is bad (even though your ram MIGHT be bad).  Good ram will hang on 21% too.

You just have to let it sit for many many hours, depending on how much ram you have and other factors such as the speed of your CPU and memory controller.

I also need to clear up a little misinformation as to how this tool reports its percentage complete.  WMDT reports the progress of each pass in the same manor that Memtest86 does:  10% or 20% or 50% etc does NOT mean that 10% or 20% or 50% of the addresses     have been tested.  the entire amount of physical ram has been tested by most of the many different algorithms by the time it hit 21%.  A pass using Extended just hits your ram with a few more different tests than Standard or Basic, but one of those extra tests takes what seems like forever, especially if you have more than 4GB.  Let us say that Extended runs ten different tests/patterns/algorithms per pass (i can't remember how many it actually runs in Extended, but let's use ten to make the math easy).  after one out of the ten tests/patterns/algorithms is finished, it will report 10% done.  after the second out of ten is finished, it will report 20% done.  Whatever test/pattern/algorithm is running when it shows 21% just happens to take a very long time.  again, I'm not saying that Extended runs ten different tests (i think it might be sixteen-ish actually), I'm just using "ten" as an example to show how the Percent Complete is calculated.

You can test this the same way that WakeDemons3 did:  rotate the ram sticks in different orders of slots, and notice that the pass still hangs on 21%, not (assuming two sticks of the same size) 71% ...